# Bleak Client: Sudden drop in reading speed

Tags: python, python-3.x, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using bleak to get data from a BLE device. After about 50 reading operations, I'm experiencing a sudden decrease in the sample rate from about 35Hz to less than 10Hz.

```
async def producer(queue: asyncio.Queue, s_eve: asyncio.Event):
    device = await bleak.BleakScanner.find_device_by_name("Some Name")
    async with bleak.BleakClient(device) as client:
        for _ in range(50):
            sample = await client.read_gatt_char("Some UUID")
            queue.put_nowait(sample)
        s_eve.set()
        loop.stop()

async def consumer(queue: asyncio.Queue, s_eve: asyncio.Event):
    start_time = time.time()
    while not s_eve.is_set():
        print(int.from_bytes(await queue.get(), "little"), abs(start_time - (start_time := time.time())))

que = asyncio.Queue()
stop_event = asyncio.Event()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [loop.create_task(producer(que, stop_event)),
         loop.create_task(consumer(que, stop_event))]
loop.run_forever()
for task in tasks:
    if not (task.cancelled() or task.done()):
        loop.run_until_complete(task)
```

Any ideas why the sample rate drops? Many thanks